# How can I reverse the order of a photo album on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, photo-sharing, facebook-photos

I believe that recent updates have removed this functionality.

Are there any tools (1st party or otherwise) that can reverse the order of an existing photo album on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to reverse the order of photos already uploaded. However, there is a way to upload and have your newest photos on top. Instead of uploading from your "Name" page, which puts newest photos on the bottom, go to your Home page, click on Photos in the left hand column and then on Add Photos when the page opens. New photos are now added to the top and will display as such, even from your "Name" page.